# How to differ unsigned n bit from signed n bit?

Tags: binary, bit, unsigned, signed

is it possible to differ unsigned n bit from signed n bit?

Since they look just the same, e.g. 10001111 can either presents 143 or -113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible, and it's not the only impossible thing. In common case you cannot even be sure that 10001111 represents 143, -113 or 42. You may invent your own way of mapping all possible binary octets to numbers or any other imaginary entities.

For example, you may treat a 64-bit integer as an efficient representation of 16-[permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation): such an integer consists of 16 [nibbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) and each of them may take 16 different values. Then you can implement permutation composition using bit-shift and bitwise logic instructions of common processors or implement your own permutation processor on (for example) FPGA with almost single-cycle permutation composition.

It's also true for any other operations on any objects you can imagine.